# Zeros of a holomorphic function of order m

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, holomorphic-functions

I define the zero of order $m$ of a function $f$ at a point $z_0$ to be such that the first $m-1$ derivatives $f^{(n)}(z_0)=0$ for $n=0,\dots,m-1$ and that $f^{(m)}(z_0) \neq 0$.

I need to prove that if a holomorphic function $f$ has a zero $z_0$ of order $m$, then it can be written as $f(z)=(z-z_0)g(z)$, where $g(z)$ is holomorphic.

I know that since $f$ is holomorphic its Taylor Series expansion around $z_0$ exists for same radius of convergence.

Since $f$ has a zero of order $m$, we can write 
\begin{align}
f(z)&=\frac{f^{(m)}(z_0)}{m!}(z-z_0)^m+\frac{f^{(m+1)}(z_0)}{(m+1)!}(z-z_0)^{m+1}+\dots\\&=(z-z_0)^m\bigg[\frac{f^{(m)}(z_0)}{m!}+\frac{f^{(m+1)}(z_0)}{(m+1)!}(z-z_0)+\dots\bigg]
\end{align}

and hence calling the thing inside the parentheses $g(z)$ it seems like I'm done.

However, I am not sure why $g(z)$ should converge and if so, why it is also holomorphic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function
$$
g_0(z)=\frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^m}
$$
is clearly holomorphic on $\Omega\setminus\{z_0\}$ (where $\Omega$ is the domain of $f$, where it is holomorphic).

It remains to show that $g_0$ has a removable singularity at $z_0$, which follows from a repeated application of l'Hôpital or by just looking at the Taylor series expansion of $f$ at $z_0$. At the end we will find that
$$
\lim_{z\to z_0}g_0(z)=\frac{f^{(m)}(z_0)}{m!}\ne0
$$

Hence we can extend $g_0$ to a function $g$ which is holomorphic on $\Omega$ and satisfies $f(z)=(z-z_0)^mg(z)$ for every $z\in\Omega$ and $g(z_0)\ne0$.

Also the converse is true: if we have $g$ holomorphic in $\Omega$, with $g(z_0)\ne0$, then $f(z)=(z-z_0)^mg(z)$ has a zero of order $m$ at $z_0$ according to your definition, by direct computation of the Taylor series at $z_0$.

Answer (score 0):

You are just dividing by $(z-z_0)^m$, so, yes, it converges. And the sum of a convergent power series is always a holomorphic function.

Comment: I think I get your argument but just to check.... $\frac{1}{(z-z_0)^m}\sum_{k=m}^{\infty} \frac{f^{(k)}(z_0)}{k!}(z-z_0)^k$ will still converge for each $z \neq z_0$ we take inside the radius of convergence since $(z-z_0)^m$ will just be some fixed number multiplying the Taylor expansion of $f$? And so effectively dividing by the polynomial is just like multiplying by a constant for each $z$ we take?

Comment: @user258521 It's not an arbitrary polynomial. It's a monomial of the type $(z-z_0)^m$. Otherwise, you wouldn't get a power series.

Comment: But if we took the monomial as you have described, then is that the logic behind why the power series still converges?

Comment: @user258521 Because, if $a\neq0$, $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(a\times a_n)$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$ converges.

Comment: Perfect, that is what I was saying then!